# Python: Twitter scraping using "request(POST)" function

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am trying to use twython package to scrap twitter data.
Due to the huge number of twitter handles that I am dealing with, I cannot use `twitter.lookup_user(user_id=user_batch)` command - so I instead tried to use 
`user_dict_batch = tw.request(user_url, method='POST')`.

Now, according to the twython documentation, the function `request` is defined as follows:

```
 request(endpoint, method='GET', params=None, version='1.1')
 Return dict of response received from Twitter’s API

 Parameters:     
 endpoint (string) – (required) Full url or Twitter API endpoint (e.g. search/tweets)
 method (string) – (optional) Method of accessing data, either GET or POST. (default GET)
 params (dict or None) – (optional) Dict of parameters accepted by Twitter API endpoint 
 version (string) – (optional) Twitter API version to access (default 1.1)

 Return type:   
 dict
```

my question is, what exactly is the "Twitter API endpoint"? For instance, if I am trying to scrap for information about the user whose twitter handle is `3Degrees_Inc`, what would be the `Twitter API endpoint` for this specific user be? I tried to use `'https://twitter.com/3Degrees_Inc'` for my value for the parameter `endpoint`, but it's keep throwing me the `Twitter API 403 (forbidden) error`....

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First, twython is a wrap-up for RESTfult twitter API, whose docs you can [find here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). So if you are interested in API [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup), its endpoint is `users/lookup`. Pay attention that this api accepts POST request, since request for that many users may exceed GET limits.

But brief walkthrough twython documentation shows that `lookup_user` is implemented in EndpointMixin and according to docs implements this same endpoint interface, so you shure can use twitter.lookup_user(user_id=[user1, user2, user3])

```
def lookup_user(self, **params):
    """Returns fully-hydrated user objects for up to 100 users per request,
    as specified by comma-separated values passed to the user_id and/or screen_name parameters.

    Docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup

    """
    return self.post('users/lookup', params=params)
```